# Блоки не становятся в колонку в бутстрапе

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Вот прикрепил два скрина разметки бутстрапа.

При масштабировании они становятся в колонку, но при открытии через панель разработчика вот что происходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужно добавить код

Comment: "вот что происходит" - а что происходит? что должно происходить? как вы задумывали адаптивность? что и на какой ширине и как должно отображаться? и добавьте в вопрос [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Проверь наличие вот этого тега в head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```